# Autocomplete textbox options from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27996960/4293747) answer is close to what I'm trying to do.  I'm also branching from its [original Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5XmPfQ78vRjSrxE0Tt3B?p=preview) to this [new Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Maj2Uh1sT2m00oubocqd?p=preview)

The original plunker has a text box that auto-completes where the auto-complete options are hard coded in a list.

I've added a service to the new plunker that gets some information about stackoverflow badges in JSON.  How can I have the auto-complete use the JSON data to provide a list of badge names for the auto-complete options?

```
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.9" data-semver="1.3.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
      var app=angular.module('app',[]);

      app.factory('badges', ['$http', function($http) {
          return $http.get('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/badges?page=1&order=desc&sort=rank&site=stackoverflow')
            .success(function(data) {
              return data;
            })
            .error(function(err) {
              return err;
            });
      }]);

      app.controller('ctrl', ['badges', function($scope, badges){

          badge_names = how do I make a list of badge names from badges.success?;
          $scope.availableTags = badge_names;
    });

    $scope.complete=function(){
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: $scope.availableTags
    });
    } 
  });
  </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div class="ui-widget">
      <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
      <input id="tags" ng-keyup="complete()"/>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, checkout this plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/IgPyrCdFqT1pn53PIqSc. It is quite simple and should be easily understandable. There probably might be better optimized ways of achieving this, than what I've done. I'm pasting the code here as well.

**Javascript**

```
<script>
  var app = angular.module('app', []);

  app.factory('badges', ['$http', function($http) {
      return $http.get('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/badges?page=1&order=desc&sort=rank&site=stackoverflow')
        .success(function(data) {
          return data;
        })
        .error(function(err) {
          return err;
        });
  }]);

  app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', 'badges', function($scope, badges){

      badgeNames = [];
      badges.then(function(response){

        for(var i=0; i < response.data.items.length; i++){
          badgeNames[i] = response.data.items[i].name;
        }

      });

      $scope.availableTags = badgeNames;
      $scope.complete = function () {
        console.log('running');
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
          source: $scope.availableTags
        });
      };
}]);
```

HTML

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
        <input id="tags" ng-keyup="complete()"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

You'll see in my code above that I traverse through the JSON to make an array consisting only of the names of badges. Ideally, that should be done via the API using filters but I wasn't familiar with the Stack Overflow API which is why, I did it that way.

Comment: Thanks.  The actual project I'm working on isn't using the Stack Overflow API, so this works perfectly.

Comment: @cameron-f Glad that I could help :-)